# Trouble with python 3.3 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: windows-7, 13.04, python3

I'm consistently getting EOF when reading a line errors on when running:

```
List0 = []
inputtedStr = input()
while inputtedStr != "#####":
    List0.append(inputtedStr)
    inputtedStr = input()
print()
print("Original List: ", List0)
List1 = []
for i in range(0, len(List0)):
    if str.strip(List0[i]) != str.strip(List0[i-1]):
        List1.append(str.strip(List0[i]))
    else:
        continue
print()
print("NO Duplicates: ", List1)
```

This runs find when I run it in a windows terminal, any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong will be greatly appreciated! Also, this is not the first time I've gotten this error only when running on Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the script with `python3`

```
~$ python Test.py 
thefourtheye
#####
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    inputtedStr = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    #####
        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

~$ python --version
Python 2.7.4

~$ python3 --version
Python 3.3.1 

~$ python3 Test.py 
WELCOME
thefourtheye
###
####
#####

Original List:  ['WELCOME', 'thefourtheye', '###', '####']

NO Duplicates:  ['WELCOME', 'thefourtheye', '###', '####']
```

or

As suggested by @MiJyn in the comments,

1. just edit your file and include the following line as the first line

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   ```
2. `chmod 755 <filename>.py`
3. `./<filename>.py`

Comment: ... or add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the top

Comment: @MiJyn Updated the answer :)